# Publicar preguntas en varias comunidades

Tags: soporte, preguntas

Necesito saber si cuando publico una pregunta en SOes, es posible publicarlo automáticamente en las otras comunidades de programadores como SO, SOru, etc.

Comment: De forma automática no es posible, tendrías que ir a cada comunidad y escribir tu pregunta en el idioma que corresponde a cada comunidad.

Comment: Quiero agregar una pregunta que esta relacionada con la inicial, acabo de publicar una pregunta en SOes, y cuando la voy a publicar en SO me dice que tengo que esperar 90 min, sé que debe ser por políticas antirobot bla bla, pero es cierto que molesta y bastante

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No es posible publicarlo automáticamente**, existen varias razones, una de ellas es principalmente que no existe una forma automática de traducción precisa de la publicación original.

Puedes realizar en cambio tu publicación manualmente en los sitios:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/

https://www.stackoverflow.com/

pero debes tomar en cuenta que tu publicación este basada en el documento del centro de ayuda: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Considera que debes estar preparado para comunicarte en los idiomas oficiales de cada sitio, esto para publicar tu pregunta y para entender las respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

De forma predeterminada las publicaciones sólo quedan en el sitio en el que fueron realizadas.

Sin embargo, existe una API de Stack Exchange la cual puede ser usada para publicar preguntas y respuestas. Lograr hacer una aplicación publique una pregunta en varios idiomas a la vez podría ser un proyecto interesante sólo ten presente que cada sitio tiene una comunidad y reglas propias así que podría darse el caso que una pregunta que sea bien recibida en uno de estos sitios en otra no lo sea.

Reference

- [Stack Exchange API V2.2 – and the demise of V1.x](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/02/10/stack-exchange-api-v2-2-and-the-demise-of-v1-x/)